# Using QThread for countdown

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am writing a trivia game using PyQt5, and I want to add a countdown for answering. I tried to use a loop and a thread, but they caused the screen to freeze. I understood that QThread could be helpful, but I didn't understand how to use it.

I have this code:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        for i in range(30):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.progress.emit(i + 1)
        self.finished.emit()

class Question:
    def __init__(self, question: tuple[str, list[str]]) -> None:
        self.question, self.answers = question
        self.true = self.answers[0]
        random.shuffle(self.answers)

    def update(self, n):
        pressed = QLabel()
        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
            pressed = answer1

        elif keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
            pressed = answer2

        elif keyboard.is_pressed('3'):
            pressed = answer3

        elif keyboard.is_pressed('4'):
            pressed = answer4

        if not pressed.isHidden():
            pressed.setStyleSheet(pressed.styleSheet() + 'border: 1px aolid black;')
    
    def present(self):
        question.setText(self.question)
        answer1.setText(f'א) {self.answers[0]}')
        answer2.setText(f'ב) {self.answers[1]}')
        answer3.setText(f'ג) {self.answers[2]}')
        answer4.setText(f'ד) {self.answers[3]}')

        t = QThread()
        w = Worker()
        w.moveToThread(t)
        t.started.connect(w.run)
        w.finished.connect(t.quit)
        w.finished.connect(w.deleteLater)
        w.finished.connect(t.deleteLater)
        w.progress.connect(self.update)
        t.start()
```

The error I get is "QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running"

Comment: Using a thread for this is pointless. Use [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html).

Comment: @musicamante will I be able to type during the run?

Comment: I wouldn't have suggested it otherwise.